# How do you really call scrolling left or right with the mouse?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I was thinking if there is one word for scrolling left or right. Usually we say **scroll** if the action is *moving a mouse wheel up or down*. 
What if we are moving it left or right?
Is it again scrolling??

Reference:
Definition from Google:
Scrolling - noun - *the action of moving displayed text or graphics up, down, or across on a computer screen in order to view different parts of them.*

Definition from Techopedia:
*Scrolling is the sliding movement of images, video or text across a display screen either vertically or horizontally. Scrolling can be done with or without user intervention.*

Related question on Superuser:
[How can I scroll horizontally with my regular mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/908178/how-can-i-scroll-horizontally-with-my-regular-mouse)

Comment: What's wrong with 'horizontal'?...

Answer (score 3):

The term **horizontal scrolling** seems to be widely used to describe the action of scrolling horizontally.

i.e.:
https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/horizsc.htm

Answer (score 3):

## *Horizontal* scrolling.

Vertical scrolling is typically just referred to as "scrolling" as the vertical is implicit, whereas horizontal scrolling requires the inclusion of the adjective to avoid confusion.